# Lagom With MySQL Db connection

Tags: mysql, playframework, akka, lagom

I want to connect lagom to MySQL db, I download a project which is created in Lagom site. I added the following dependency in to the hello-impl pom, and applicaiont.conf configure the db details.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.lightbend.lagom</groupId>
        <artifactId>lagom-javadsl-persistence-jdbc_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${lagom.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

aplication.conf

```
db.default {
  driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
  user = "root"
  password = ""
}
jdbc-defaults.slick.profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
lagom.persistence.jdbc.create-tables.auto = true
```

after that I run the application i got the following error. what is the mistake.
i'm new in lagom so please explain detail.

```
{"name":"akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://hello-impl-application/system/sharding/HelloEntity#976224651]] after [10000 ms]. Message of type [com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.persistence.CommandEnvelope]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.","detail":"akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://hello-impl-application/system/sharding/HelloEntity#976224651]] after [10000 ms]. Message of type [com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.persistence.CommandEnvelope]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.\r\n\tat akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$.$anonfun$defaultOnTimeout$1(AskSupport.scala:635)\r\n\tat akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$.$anonfun$apply$1(AskSupport.scala:650)\r\n\tat akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:205)\r\n\tat scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:870)\r\n\tat scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)\r\n\tat scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute$(BatchingExecutor.scala:103)\r\n\tat scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:868)\r\n\tat akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:328)\r\n\tat akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:279)\r\n\tat akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:283)\r\n\tat akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:235)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\r\n"}
```

Answer (score 2):

While using MySQL we need to create the database itself. In Cassandra, it creates keyspace after defining a name in conf file but in MySQL, we have to manually create a database say ***test*** in your case ->

> create database test;

then you won't face Ask timed out exception.